# Outputting multiple elements within <a> using CakePHP HTML Helper

Tags: cakephp

I'd like to know if this code...

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    "<h3>test</h3>".$this->Html->image("image.jpg")."<p>Some text</p>",
    "/link",
    array('escape' => false)
);
```

...is the best way to generate this HTML in CakePHP...

```
<a href="/path/to/link">
    <h3>test</h3>
    <img alt="" src="/path/to/image.jpg">
    <p>Some text</p>
</a>
```

Or, is there a more "correct" way of doing this? I want the   and

all to be within the  tag so that I can set the  to `display: block;` in CSS and have the whole area clickable with a hover effect.

Something tells me that having HTML echoed like this isn't the right way to go about it, but I can't see an alternative if I'm going to use the HTML Helper. Is there one?

Comment: In HTML 4, placing a *block element* like `<p>` inside an *inline element* like `<a>` is incorrect to begin with.

Comment: Ok, but let's say I was doing it in HTML5...  would there be another way of doing it in Cake other than how I wrote above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the URL method of the HTML helper instead of the link one,do the rest as static HTML, may as well keep the amount of PHP down to a minimum as far as I see it.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url($params); ?>">
    <h3>test</h3>
    <?php echo $this->Html->image($params); ?>
    <p>Some text</p>
</a>
```

This would be the most *efficient* way of doing this task. But maybe you should think about your markup structure and what you want to achieve...

Comment: Thanks @Dunhamzzz -- that achieves what I wanted to do with the minimum of code and fuss. I appreciate your comments relating to the HTML structure too. I know it's not the correct way to do things in HTML4 but all I have to do at this stage is duplicate a HTML structure which has already been created. Making it compliant will be the next phase. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
$this->Html->tag('li',
                     $this->Html->link(
                     '<i class="entypo-book"></i>'.
                     $this->Html->tag('span', $nom
                     .$this->Html->tag('span', '32', array('class' => 'badge'))
                     ),
                     array('controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index'),
                     array('class' => 'active', 'title' => 'Pages', 'escape' => false)
                     )
                 );
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation, so readers will know *why* you do it that way.

Comment: Yes, it can be done like that. But, as per my original question, I was looking for a more efficient way to do it that didn't involve echoing HTML like that.